# Optimising the computation of a (quasi) infinite series on Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I have a time series stored in a pandas dataframe. The time series is the sequence {`X_t`} where `t` is the time index that in my case it is truncated, i.e. t = [0,T>0].

For each `t`, I would like to compute the following series

[image]

where the weights `w_k` are defined by a recursive relation

[image]

and `d` is a float parameter between 0 and 1.

Of course, given that my series is not infinite, this sum must be truncated. For example, for the last two terms of the time series, I will compute

[image]

I have tried to implement this computation in python, but it is terribly slow and I am sure I am not using the full potential of pandas/numpy. Can anyone suggest me a better way to do this computation?

First of all, I create a random dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 1)), columns=['value'])
```

then, I create a function that computes the weights iteratively

```
def get_next_weight(weight, k, d):
    return - weight * (d-k+1)/k

weights = [1]
idx = 1
for idx in range(1,len(df)):
    weights.append(get_next_weight(weights[-1], idx, 0.1))
```

Then, I compute the new series

```
new_values = []

with tqdm(total=len(df)) as pbar:
    for idx in df.index:
        Xt = (df.value.loc[:idx].sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True) * weights[:idx+1]).sum()
        new_values.append(Xt)
        pbar.update(1)
```

This is really slow, and I know that my solution is very bad, but I couldn't come up with a better clean solution.

Any help?

Comment: Why are you sorting the values? You don't address that in your explanation.

Comment: @jared I am sorting the indexes because the first weight must multiply the last element of the time series for each $t$.

Comment: can't you find a recursive approach between `X_t` and `X_t+1` ?

Comment: working with pandas is slower than numpy.  And this `(df.value.loc[:idx].sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)` looks like it will be extra slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-stage optimization:

- *weights*: instead of *loop/append/indexing* create a numpy array of weights using list comprehension with calculating each weight on the fly
- *"new" values*: instead of locating/sorting the index of each consecutive slice of values, operate on *raw* numpy arrays reversing each slice of values with `[::-1]`

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 1)), columns=['value'])

def get_next_weight(weight, k, d):
    return -weight * (d - k + 1)/k

w = 1
weights = np.array([w] + [(w := get_next_weight(w, i, 0.1)) for i in df.index[1:]])

new_values = [(df['value'].values[:i + 1][::-1] * weights[:i + 1]).sum()
              for i in df.index]
```

---

Your initial approach was running in about **6 minutes** on my machine, while my approach works out in about **7 seconds**.

Sample result fragment:

```
print(new_values[:10])

[8.0, 6.2, 10.940000000000001, 1.2570000000000003, 31.795200000000005, 58.9494285, 49.66343665, 24.988227842500006, -6.947859277874997, 8.43163034610313]
```

Comment: Note: this solution makes use of the walrus operator, `:=`, which is only available in Python 3.8 or later.

Comment: Amazing :) Thank you for this solution. I didn't know the existence of the walrus operator. Thanks!